# Linq - NHibernate - get all classes where the dictionary property contains one of the items from my list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, nhibernate, linq-to-nhibernate

I'm having a class foo like

```
foo 
{
Dictionary<string, Blubb> blubbDict {get;set;}
Dictionary<Bar, string> barDict {get;set;}
}
```

Now i'd like to load all objects from the database where blubbDict containts a key "FooBar"
and where barDict contains any objects Bar which i have locally in a List barList.

What i got so far:

```
var fooQuery = from c in session.Query<Foo>()
               where c.blubbDict.ContainsKey("FooBar")
               select c;
```

which works so far.
But what about my last condition. I'd like only the Foo objects where both conditions meet "FooBar" AND the key of barDict is in my local List.

Can anyone help me? I can't get my head around that problem.

Comment: Do you mean to have a Bar Object mapping to a string?

Comment: No Bar is a class. Shouldn't map to a string. I just have some Bar objects locally in a List<bar>.

Comment: Right but a Dictionary Maps objects, so you are having your Bar Object map to a string?  What are you trying to do with your barDict? Maybe a different collection would make it easier?

Comment: Yes. Cause there is no other way in NHibernate atm. The string is describing the Bar object and is stored in the mapping table. It's <many-to-many> mapping. The only way i could do that with a Set etc is introducing a new object. "BarInformation" which holds the string a "Information"-property and referencing Bar but i don't want and need another layer.

Answer (score 2):

Never tried to do it so I'm not absolutely sure Linq For NH supports it but you can try:

```
var fooQuery = session.Query<Foo>()
                      .Where(c => c.blubbDict.ContainsKey("FooBar"))
                      .Where(c => barList.Any(b => c.barDict.ContainsKey(b)));
```